# Testing Backup and Restore Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded

Tags: android, backup, restore

I am following instruction on https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/testingbackup.html

However, I appears after a few time of restore from command line tool,I get the following output from logcat and I can't restore, it appears I reached the daily limit for and unauthenticated user, does anyone know how to overcome this issue? ( I am logged in on google drive)

```
{
    "error":{
        "errors":[
            {
                "domain":"usageLimits",
                "reason":"dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
                "message":"Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
                "extendedHelp":"https://code.google.com/apis/console"
            }
        ],
        "code":403,
        "message":"Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
    }
}
```

[image: another issue]

```
01-30 15:49:52.212 1222-2796/? E/Backup: [CacheRestoreHelper] Restore token not found.
                                         java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/files/d2d_restore_data/restore_token_file: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                             at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
                                             at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
                                             at loe.a(:com.google.android.gms:226)
                                             at gev.a(:com.google.android.gms:2201)
                                             at geq.b(:com.google.android.gms:617)
                                             at geq.getAvailableRestoreSets(:com.google.android.gms:608)
                                             at android.app.backup.BackupTransport$TransportImpl.getAvailableRestoreSets(BackupTransport.java:588)
                                             at com.android.internal.backup.IBackupTransport$Stub.onTransact(IBackupTransport.java:170)
                                             at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
                                             at bxp.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms:35)
                                             at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
                                          Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                             at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
                                             at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
                                             at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
                                             at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76) 
                                             at loe.a(:com.google.android.gms:226) 
                                             at gev.a(:com.google.android.gms:2201) 
                                             at geq.b(:com.google.android.gms:617) 
                                             at geq.getAvailableRestoreSets(:com.google.android.gms:608) 
                                             at android.app.backup.BackupTransport$TransportImpl.getAvailableRestoreSets(BackupTransport.java:588) 
                                             at com.android.internal.backup.IBackupTransport$Stub.onTransact(IBackupTransport.java:170) 
                                             at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387) 
                                             at bxp.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms:35) 
                                             at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
```